# Why the compiler outputs the following error codes: C2143, C2238, C2501

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

I might be quite rusty in C++ since I sincerely don't know the reason of such errors.
The code is actually quite simple. (VS2003)

```
#include <vector>

class store
{
public:
    vector<int>storage;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the small, self-contained example and not posting 1000 lines of irrelevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to add `std::` in front of `vector`:

```
std::vector<int>storage;
```

The `vector` class is inside the `std` namespace.

---

Or just add

```
using namespace std;
```

which is **highly NOT** recommended, especially for header files.

Comment: @ViniyoShouta - take it easy :D Everybody makes simple mistakes.